# How to download spaCy models in a Poetry managed environment

Tags: python, nlp, spacy, python-poetry, virtual-environment

I am writing a Python Jupyter notebook that does some NLP processing on Italian texts.

I have installed spaCy 3.5.3 via Poetry and then attempt to run the following code:

```py
import spacy
load_model = spacy.load('it_core_news_sm')
```

The `import` line works as expected, but running `spacy.load` produces the following error:

> OSError: [E050] Can't find model 'it_core_news_sm'. It doesn't seem to be a Python package or a valid path to a data directory.
> The model name is correct as shown on https://spacy.io/models/it

After a web search, I see that a solution is to issue the following command:

```
python3 -m spacy download it_core_news_sm
```

After running this command the above code works as expected, however, is there a more 'kosher' way of doing this via Poetry?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can [add a URL dependency](https://python-poetry.org/docs/dependency-specification/#url-dependencies). First edit your `pyproject.toml` file to add the following (note: the name used here should match the name of the package (i.e. `it_core_news_sm`):

```ini
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
it_core_news_sm = {url = "https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/it_core_news_sm-3.5.0/it_core_news_sm-3.5.0.tar.gz"}
```

Then run the corresponding `add` call:

```
poetry add https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/it_core_news_sm-3.5.0/it_core_news_sm-3.5.0.tar.gz
```

All of the spaCy models can be found on spaCy's [model releases](https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/) GitHub page.

Comment: Thanks a lot my friend !!! You solved my problem AND taught me something new! :) Now I am bogged with poetry unable to install numpy and tensorflow :( :( :( what a nightmare!

Comment: @RobertAlexander You're welcome, glad I could help! What errors are you receiving now, or did you manage to get those packages installed?

Comment: Neither on Linux server/AMD nor on Mac/M1 or Mac/M2 ... poetry add numpy tensorflow just aborts with no resolvable versions :( Tired relaxing python levels (3.9.x or 3.10.x) and tried numpy and transformers = * in pyproject,toml but no solution :(

Comment: @RobertAlexander That is bizarre. I know Tensorflow can temperamental to install but usually numpy is straightforward. It might be worth posting a question on SO with a minimal reproducible example to see if you can get some help. Alternatively, have you thought about just using a standard virtual environment and creating a requirements.txt file? Or is there are particular reason you are keen on using Poetry instead of the pip/venv combo?

Comment: @KyleF.Hartzenberg Thank you for your contribution. Just a quick shot: it seems to me that running `poetry add <package>` is precisely what adds dependencies to `pyproject.toml` in the `[tool.poetry.dependencies]` section. If you're adding the dependency manually in `pyproject.toml`, you shall then run `poetry install`